# What is the most efficient way to query a mysql database multiple times with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to figure out the most efficient way to send multiple queries to a MySQL database with PHP. Right now I'm doing two separate queries but I know there are more efficient methods, like using `mysqli_multi_query`. Is `mysqli_multi_query` the most efficient method or are there other means?

For example, I could just write a query that puts ALL the data from ALL the tables in the database into a PHP array. Then I could sort the data using PHP, resulting in having only one query no matter what data I needed... and I could put that PHP array into a session variable so the user would never query the database again during that session. Makes sense right? Why not just do that rather than create a new query each time the page is reloaded?

It's really difficult to find resources on this so I'm just looking for advice. I plan to have massive traffic on the site that I am building so I need the code to put as little stress on the server as possible. As far as table size is concerned, we're talking about, let's say 3,000 rows in the largest table. Is it feasible to store that into one big PHP array (advantage being the client would query the database only ONCE on page load)?

```
$Table1Array = Array();
$Table1_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE column1 ='" . $somevariable . "'");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Table1_result))
  {


  $Table1Array[] = $row;

  } 


// query 2
$Table2Array = Array();
$Table2_result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Table2 LIMIT 5");
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Table2_result))
  {


  $Table2Array[] = $row;

  }
```

Comment: Use a function and change parameters every time you are using the function

Comment: @believeme I'm not sure that would help here. Notice the queries are different. It's not quite that easy...

Comment: Avoid it if you can be using JOINS and UNIONS where appropriate to keep the number of database queries you execute to a minimum; use prepared statements where you do need to repeat queries with different arguments

Comment: ["Premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29) -- Donald Knuth. Don't worry too much about "massive traffic" until you have it. Of course, write efficient code where you can, but getting distracted by optimization can be a big problem.

Comment: More efficient in what sense? CPU? Time? Memory? Network overhead? For the server PHP runs on, or for the database server? Big arrays in the requests are also fleeting, the next request they're already gone. The query cache in the database is a lot more efficient and long lived (assuming data doesn't change), cache in `apc` or `memcached` can be anything from the simple to complex objects to completely prerendered HTML snippets, but is a bit harder to invalidate.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ...` is the *least* efficient way to retrieve data (explicitly select *only* the columns you need). `SELECT...LIMIT` without an ORDER BY is nonsense

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to address here, hopefully this will make sense / be constructive...

> Is mysqli_multi_query the most efficient method or are there other
>   means?

It depends on the *specifics* of what you are trying to do for a given page / query. Generally speaking though, using `mysql_multi_query` won't gain you much performance, as MySQL will still execute the queries you give it one after the other. `mysql_multi_query`'s performance gains come from the fact that fewer round trips are made between PHP and MySQL. A good thing if the two are on different servers, or you are performing 1000s of queries one after the other.

> For example, I could just write a query that puts ALL the data from
>   ALL the tables in the database into a PHP array.

Just. No. In theory you could, but unless you had one page that displayed **all** of the database contents at once, there would simply be no need.

> Then I could sort the data using PHP

If you can sort / filter the data into the correct form using MySQL, do that. Manipulating datasets is one of the things MySQL is very good at.

> Why not just [load everything into the session] rather than create a new query each time the page is reloaded?

Because the dataset would be huge, and that session data would be transferred from the client every time they made a request to your server. Apart from sending needlessly huge requests, what about the other challenges this approach would raise? I.e. What would you do if extra data had been added to the db since you created the session-based cache for this particular user? What if the size of the data got too big for a user's session? What experience would I have as a user if I denied your session cookie and thereby forced the monster query to execute on *every* request?

> I plan to have massive traffic on the site that I am building

Don't we all! As the comments above suggest, premature optimization is a Bad Thing. At this stage you should concentrate on getting your [domain logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic) nailed down and building a good, maintainable OO platform on which to base further development.

Answer (score 1):

```
For example, I could just write a query that puts ALL the data from ALL the tables in 
the database into a PHP array. Then I could sort the data using PHP, resulting in having 
only one query no matter what data I needed...
```

I would think this would be inefficient since you've lost the value of the Database. When you consider optimization, mysql is superior to any php code that you could write.

Additionally, you're saying that running one query, pushing the data into a variable for the users may decrease resources but is that really true? If you have massive traffic, and this data are in session variables, then if 1000 users are currently logged on then you will have 1000 duplications of the entire Database on your PHP server! - you sure the server has enough memory for this?

There are 2 ways I use to run multiple queries:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("host", "dbuser", "password");

$query1 = "select.......";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die (mysql_error()); // execute the query
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    // fetch the results from the query
}

$query2 = "select.......";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die (mysql_error()); // execute the query
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
{
    // fetch the results from the query i.e. $row2['']
}

mysql_close($conn); // Close the Database connection.
```

The other way is to employ the use of transactions if there are more than one queries which must be either all executed or none at all

You could try it. But if the only reason is to have 1 query thinking that it will be faster, I would think otherwise. Optimizations in Databases are supreme especially mysql

Answer (score 1):

If i wanted to execute multiple queries on a mysql database i would use mysql stored procedures and then all u have to do is issue a simple call from php, a basic example of a procedure would be:

```
DELIMITER $$
create procedure multiple_queries()

Begin
SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE 1;
SELECT * FROM TBL2 WHERE 2;
SELECT * FROM TBL3 LEFT JOIN ON TBL4 WHERE id= '121';
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

and in php you simple call the procedure and any parameter associated with it in the parenthesis

```
CALL multiple_queries()
```

Why not use the DB engine as much as possible, its well capable of handling complex solutions and we dont utilize it.